# Objects, In Vector, Being Corrupted In 'For Loop' Initialization

Tags: c++, vector, memory-corruption

My problem is as follows: 
I am designing a small game; however, I have run into a very large problem, which I have been trying to fix for some time now. Essentially, I want to upgrade buildings, if the use has enough points, but the data in the `Building` objects are being corrupted. The only object which is as it is 'supposed' to be, is the first allocated object in the `buildings` `vector`.
Building Class:

When I run the program I am faced with a black screen (meaning it began properly); and when I debug, I get an error like such: `Access violation reading location 0x00000008`. Meaning a `NULL` value has been used.

```
class Building {
    public:
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        vector<int> buildingID;
        vector<int> upgradeCost;

        int size = 4;

        Building(vector<int> buildingID, int x, int y, vector<int> upgradeCost) 
        : buildingID(buildingID), x(x), y(y), upgradeCost(upgradeCost) { }

        virtual void upgrade();
        void drawTile(SDL_Rect, SDL_Surface*);

        int buildingLevel = 1;

    protected:
    };

    void Building::upgrade() {
        if((buildingLevel+1) <= size)buildingLevel += 1;
    }

    void Building::drawTile(SDL_Rect drawRect, SDL_Surface* drawnTo) {
        Tile::Tiles.at(buildingID[buildingLevel - 1]).drawTile(drawRect, drawnTo);
    }
```

The function which generates the buildings:

```
void Level::generateTerrain() {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                int tile = rand()%100;
                if (tile >= 25 && tile <= 28) this->tiles.at(i + (j*this->width)) = 2;
                else if (tile < 24) this->tiles.at(i + (j*this->width)) = 1;
                else if (tile == 29) {
                    this->addBuilding(Building(vector<int>{4, 3, 2, 1}, i * 75, j * 75, vector<int>{1, 1, 1, 1}), i, j);
                }
                else this->tiles.at(i + (j*this->width)) = 0;
            }
    }
```

The function which adds buildings:

```
void Level::addBuilding(Building building, int x, int y) {
        buildings.push_back(building);
        tiles.at(x + (y*this->width)) = buildID(building.buildingID[building.buildingLevel-1], &buildings.at(buildings.size()-1));
    }
```

And lastly the function which draws the Tiles/Buildings:

```
void Level::drawLevel(int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Surface* drawnTo, int beginningX, int beginningY) {
        SDL_Rect tempRect;
        tempRect.w = 75;
        tempRect.h = 75;

        for (int i = x; i <= (x + width); i++)
            for (int j = y; j <= (y + height); j++) {
            if (tiles.at(i + (j*this->width)).id == 999999) continue;

            tempRect.x = (i*Tile::Tiles.at(tiles.at(i + (j*this->width)).id).tileSurface->w) + beginningX;
            tempRect.y = (j*Tile::Tiles.at(tiles.at(i + (j*this->width)).id).tileSurface->h) + beginningY;

            Tile::Tiles.at(tiles.at(i + (j*this->width)).id).drawTile(tempRect, drawnTo);
            }
    }
```

If you require any more pieces of the code, please just ask.
Thanks for any help given.

Comment: You can shorten that constructor to:  `Building(vector<int> buildingID, int x, int y, vector<int> upgradeCost) : buildingID(buildingID), x(x), y(y), upgradeCost(upgradeCost) {}`. Also, if you need a constant size, consider using [`std::array<int, 4>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)

Comment: That's helpful, thank you. I have kind of resolved in hard-coding everything, just to try and fix the problem.

Comment: There's another bug you might not even be aware of yet: You seem to be storing objects of type `Building` in a standard container. These will copy the stored elements though, but if you pass it an object derived from `Building`, it will create and init an object of type `Building` with this, i.e. the object's type will be truncated. Also, if your type has virtual functions, it probably also needs a virtual destructor and it should prevent copy-construction and assignment.

Comment: Thanks Ulrich Eckhardt, I will consider that; however, I don't believe it is what triggered the error. Nonetheless, thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only part of your code that looks suspect to me is how in addBuilding() you are using the address of an element in the vector in the second parameter to buildID(). Vector class re-allocates the memory it uses when it needs to grow in capacity, so existing elements will likely no longer be at the same address your pointers point to when this happens.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer; I do believe this to be the problem. Do you have any suggestions for the path I should take for this?

Comment: I see two possible options, either rework your code that uses the pointer to get the building out of the buildings vector instead, or set the capacity of your buildings vector to some maximum limit when you create it and don't let addBuilding() exceed that (using vector::reserve() function), then your pointers should be safe to use as long as you don't remove elements from the vector.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for all your help. I have changed my code to reference the element number, instead of the element its self.